# REP training - 35 hours expiry

Tags: certification

I have attended a class room training from a REP two years back and some how I was not able to prepare for the exam and I didn't register with PMI either. Now I want to attend the exam and going to register. the training I attended two years back is eligible for 35 contact hours for now or do i need to get training again?
Appreciate your feedback.

Thanks
PP

Answer (score 2):

You're fine, as long as you have some proof that you attended that course.

The time of education doesn't matter (even college courses about project management comply). The PMP handbook clearly states

> *Record all education hours regardless of when they were accrued.*

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - you do not need another training to fulfil 35 hour contact requirement.

35 contact hours do not expire. For more details, you can read this article - http://www.pmbypm.com/pmp-pdu-validity/

However, attending another training has many advantages. The main advantage is that you get access to latest exam material. You should read the following article to understand all the advantages.

6 Reasons To Do A PMP Training Again - http://www.pmbypm.com/pmp-training-again/